# Trying to create a category for NSArray, but do not understand why the thread stalls/breaks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, categories

I'm trying to follow team treehouse's course on objective-C.

This part, the course is trying to teach us about implementing categories. So I have the code below

main.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "NSArray+mahem.h"
int main()
{
    NSArray *letters = @[ @"alfa", @"bravo", @"charlie"];
    NSLog(@"letters %@", letters);

    NSLog(@"cap %@", [letters capitalizeStrings]);
    return 0;
}
```

NSArray+mahem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (mahem)
-(NSArray *)capitalizeStrings;
@end
```

NSArray+mahem.m

```
#import "NSArray+mahem.h"

@implementation NSArray (mahem)
-(NSArray *)capitalizeStrings{
    NSMutableArray *cap = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *string in self) {
        [cap addObject:[string capitalizedString]];
    }
    return cap;

}
@end
```

Basically, I am trying to capitalize every word in the NSArray `letters`. However, when I run main.m in xcode 6, the program reaches a breakpoint at the line `for (NSString *string in self) {` in the file `NSArray+mahem.m`.

I have never used the xcode debugger before, so am unsure what I'm seeing or how I should fix this. It seems to say that `self` does have 3 objects (@"alfa", @"bravo", @"charlie"), but `cap` has 0, and `string` apparently equals 0xa1a1a1a1. I'm assuming this means it broke on the first loop, or else `cap` would have at least one object. Why did `string` get gibberish?

Is this because NSArray is const and is not mutable? How do I fix this? If anyone can explain this to me, it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: The code works perfectly.  Perhaps you set a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: @avi hmm, maybe I did. I did not notice this. I started a new project and it does run perfectly. Maybe I did set a break point and did not notice. Thanks for your help, I'm still new to using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, everything works just fine. When execution flow gets to the string `for (NSString *string in self) {`

1. Your `self` array is fully populated - it was created previously in `main()`
2. Your `cap` has been declared and initialized, but not populated - `for` loop wasn't executed once.
3. Your `string` was declared but not initialized - it exists, but points to some random place in memory. It is not broken. If you'll step over in debugger, you will see, that `string` becomes `@"alpha"`, but `cap` is still empty. One more step over - `string` is still `@"alpha"` and `cap` is populated with one object.

Everything should work fine. Feel free to ask anything left unclear

Comment: Yeah, I made another project and copy-and-pasted all the code and it did run perfectly, so I probably set a break point by mistake. Thanks for your help. Also this is a great explanation of what happens. I do have a background in c++ and python, so I think i understand it well, but the syntax in obj-c just looks wacky. Thanks!